# Pandas apply to index

Tags: pandas

I have a df that has some columns and a multi-index with bytes datatype. to clean the columns I can do

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x: x.decode('UTF-8'))
```

and for a single index this should work

```
df.index.map(lambda x: x.decode('UTF-8'))
```

But it appears to fail with multi-index. Is there anything similar I can do for the multi-index?

EDIT:
example

```
pd.DataFrame().from_dict({'val': {(b'A', b'a'): 1,
  (b'A', b'b'): 2,
  (b'B', b'a'): 3,
  (b'B', b'b'): 4,
  (b'B', b'c'): 5}})
```

and the desired output it

```
pd.DataFrame().from_dict({'val': {('A', 'a'): 1,
  ('A', 'b'): 2,
  ('B', 'a'): 3,
  ('B', 'b'): 4,
  ('B', 'c'): 5}})
```

Comment: Can you do `df.head(5).to_dict()` and paste that output here so it is easy to reproduce your problem? Would also be great if you'd add in your expected output.

Comment: edited to show an example

Comment: did you try to `reset_index`, then perform the tasks on all the columns and then `set_index`to get the original MultiIndex back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(x[0].decode('utf-8'), x[1].decode('utf-8')) for x in df.index])
```

%timeit result: `1000 loops, best of 3: 573 µs per loop`

**Method 2:**

```
df.reset_index().set_index('val').applymap(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')).reset_index().set_index(['level_0', 'level_1'])
```

%timeit result: `100 loops, best of 3: 4.17 ms per loop`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was hoping for some one-liner like this

Answer (score 2):

```
df.index.levels = ([ names.map(lambda x: x.decode('UTF-8')) for i, names in enumerate(df.index.levels)])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
        val
A   a   1
    b   2
B   a   3
    b   4
    c   5
```